# Get event/notification when user click phone call at Gmail/Hangout

Tags: gmail, google-hangouts

Is there any way to get notification when user initiates new call in gmail via google talk or hangout? The purpose to track it is to extract extension which user wants to call and initiate call using third-party application instead of google services.
I checked google talk API and hangout API but haven't found any similiar to that.